# How to make animation like this?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

Hello everyone hope you all are doing I am a newbie in Flutter / dart I want to make an animation on scrolling like this check the video please {https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SI-v2aecQCAL7ud0A5_eu1wZn30bxC-t/view?usp=sharing}

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SI-v2aecQCAL7ud0A5_eu1wZn30bxC-t/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance......................................................................................

Comment: i really dont understand your request

Comment: @JhonSabowsla I want to add animation in my same like the animation in a video (check the drive link) animation on  scrolling thee page

Answer (score 0):

for that you will need to use a ScrollController and keep track of the offset of the ScrollController, every time you update the scrollcontroller, you can add a listener so it updates the curve behind the page, and using a customPainter you can animate the curve points

something along these lines

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.addListener(updateCurve);
    super.initState();
  }

  void updateCurve() {
    print(controller.offset);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        //Background
        CustomPaint(
          painter: CurvePainter(
            offset: controller.offset,
          ),
          child: Container(),
        ),
        ListView(
          controller: controller,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  CurvePainter({required this.offset});

  final double offset;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //Drive your curve here according to the offset
    // TODO: implement paint
  }    

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```